# Programmatically clicking all buttons on a page in Chrome's console

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, console

I'm trying to use the Chrome console to select all the buttons in a page and click them programmatically. A similar page to what I'm playing with is this one: http://api.openstack.org/api-ref.html#compute-ext

I already tried to execute the command below but it didn't do what I wanted.

```
$("btn small info").click()
```

Is this possible at all? What command should I issue?

Comment: Classes? `$(".btn.small.info").click();`

Comment: you might also want to delay the clicks... Just a thought, but clicking all buttons at the same time might give weird effects depending on their actual behavior.

Comment: Delaying the clicks was not necessary in this case.

Comment: Can someone help me about this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24043355/typeerror-cannot-read-property-click-of-null

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, you want to make sure you only select the buttons in the section so you are not running the search.

```
$("#body .btn").trigger("click");
```

Comment: This is the perfect solution. The `#body` is required for correct operation.

Comment: Error on Chromium 50.0 on Linux: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).trigger is not a function(…)`.

Comment: @pevik my guess is there is no jQuery on the page which this solution uses.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the page already has jQuery libraries included (which the referenced page does), then:

```
$(".btn.small.info").click();
```

This will implicitly iterate through all selectors with those three classes, and simulate a click event.

If the page does not have the necessary jQuery libraries, then try this before executing the command above:

```
var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
jQuery.noConflict();
```

Note that the command you're using in your question will not select elements of class btn etc. You must use a dot to select a `.class`.

Answer (score 6):

Based on Salketers comment to the question, here's a little script that will programatically click all buttons one by one at a 1 second interval, and also log the clicked button to the console:

```
var buttons = $("button"), 
    interval = setInterval(function(){
        var btn = $(buttons.splice(0, 1));
        console.log("Clicking:", btn);
        btn.click();
        if (buttons.length === 0) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: HI old thread but wondered if an explanation was available. What doe the splice method achieve. Im guessing remove each button from the array as it is clicked?

Comment: @James That's correct :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Answer (score 5):

Your class seems to be missing the `.`.
Try one of these:

```
$(".btn").click();
$("button").click();
$("input:submit").click();
$(".btn.small.info").click();
```

Comment: All of these select only first button (on page with more), what's wrong? Chromium 50.0 on Linux.

Comment: $(".delete").click(); -->  This worked like a charm  Thx!

Answer (score 4):

Your selector may be wrong.
Try doing something like this

```
$(".btn.small.info").click();
```

That will click a button with the classes `btn small info`, what you had was trying to click dom elements.

Here is more documentation on jQuery selectors:

- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/jquery-selectors.htm
- http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

Answer (score 4):

[**Simple solution for newbies**] Use below to click on all the matched element

```
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName('followBtn')
for (var i =0; i<btns.length; i++) 
btns[i].click();
```

Can be used with tag names as well.

**Or you can also use Xpaths to define specific elements** Use below code sample

```
*//Xpath to get all the elements whose class is "followBtn" and tagname button*
var btns = $x('//button[@class="followBtn"]')

*// looping through all the elements in btns*
for (var i =0; i<btns.length; i++) 
btns[i].click();
```