# Autoclick for Facebook

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, facebook

I'm basically trying to find out the easiest way of adding people within a Facebook group.

I'm having to click 'add' one by one.

I've done some research into the topic and found that Facebook disables jQuery (which is weird). I've tried all of these examples listed within [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17300364/programmatically-clicking-all-buttons-on-a-page-in-chromes-console) on the console.

Code to button:

```
<div class="pts"><span class="FriendLink" id="u_4p_n"><a class="uiIconText addButton" href="#" style="padding-left: 18px;" role="button"><i class="img sp_JSy08jQWU_v sx_03b2f3" style="top: 2px;"></i>Add Friend</a><span class="enableFriendListFlyout outgoingButton hidden_elem outgoingButton" data-profileid="83302251"><span class="fcg">Request sent</span></span></span></div>
```

Comment: Why do you want to generate automatic traffic for Facebook. It may be detected as spam :)

Comment: "adding people within a Facebook group." those people who requested to join your group, right?