# click requests using mootools

Tags: javascript, jquery, console, mootools

I need this jQuery code

```
$(".a.follow").click();
```

to transfer into Mootools command.
Can someone help me please?

(( I want to send automated - mass clicks all over the page using google chrome developer tools - console ))

Related to : [TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24043355/typeerror-cannot-read-property-click-of-null)

Answer (score 1):

That code in jQuery fires a click event on that/those elements. The translation of that in MooTools would be the [fireEvent method](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element.Event#Element%3afireEvent) and passing "click" ad the event type to fire.

```
$$(".a.follow").fireEvent('click');
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/n3kAw/

Comment: ALSO. selector .a.follow implies `class="a follow"`, possibly meant `'a.follow'` for an A element(s). OP may also want to consider throttling this a little since if each handler has an ajax request, it may cause nnn requests at the same time. `.each(function(el, i){ el.fireEvent.delay(i * 200, el, 'click') }` will add 200ms delay between each request.

Comment: Very good point @DimitarChristoff. Berque, please clarify if you are looking for elements with both 2 classes OR a link/anchor with class 'follow'

Comment: I am really glad for your answers @Sergio and Dimitar Christoff
But the code simply just doesn't click.
Please check this photo out first; ( properties of the button )
http://prntscr.com/3qf2vg


And then look at this; ( what happens when I run the code )
http://prntscr.com/3qf3a1

Comment: @BerqueCemilian do you have a live link?

Comment: Hello @Sergio , unfortunately I don't have a directly working link. But if you have a "Vine" account, you can simply go that address; https://client.vineclient.com/ ; and install google chrome plug-in, then log in to you account and see all of them alive.. Thank you so so so much!

Comment: depends how the handlers are done. if they use event delegation, then the above won't work - show where the events are being bound.

Comment: Sorry I couldnt understand what should I do / how? :/