# Selecting a combo box using selenium webdriver xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I need to be able to select a element in a combo box, using xpath seems to be the way to do it. i found the path and the id of the box which is

```
Path = div/div/div
ID = stuff_devicessettings_Modbus_TCP
```

I tried several different ways to open the box here is some of my failed attempts

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div/div/div[contains(text(),'No Device Connected')]").click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div/div/div[@id ='stuff_devicessettings_Modbus_TCP']//div/div/div[text()=""No Device Connected"])
```

But none of it was successful, Please help me find out a way to open and select an element from a combo box.

Here is what is contained

```
<select data-bind="uid: uid + '_device', options: devices, optionsText: 'name', optionsCaption:     
strings.notConnected, optionsAfterRender: applyDeviceAvailability, value: selectedDevice,  
enable: 
canModifyDevice" id="stuff_devicessettings_Modbus_TCP"><option value="">No device 
connected</option><option value="">Create a new device</option></select>
```

Comment: Could you show the HTML containing the element, or better share the link to the website, if possible. Thanks.

Comment: Ok i added what is contained,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Selenium has a special way of handling `select`->`option` elements - a [`Select` class](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select). Find your `select` tag by id, instantiate a `Select` class and [select an option by visible text](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select.select_by_visible_text):

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('stuff_devicessettings_Modbus_TCP'))
select.select_by_visible_text("No device connected")
```

Comment: One problem i am having is i am getting the error, Cannot read property 'click' of null.   What do you think could cause this error

Comment: Does this link help, @aaronbill? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24043355/typeerror-cannot-read-property-click-of-null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24043355/typeerror-cannot-read-property-click-of-null)