# How to click on some button in a web-page with Chrome's Console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-devtools

I've read this answer: [Programmatically clicking all buttons on a page in Chrome's console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17300364/programmatically-clicking-all-buttons-on-a-page-in-chromes-console)

But I'm not be able to fix it for my specific case, because I need to click just one button and I can't find a way to select it, using the name.

The page is this one, for instance: http://ask.fm/god and I would like to select and click the button "view more".

Comment: I'm not sure why you couldn't figure this out... `$('.submit-button-more').click()`

Comment: @PedroEstrada And its sans-jQuery equivalent: `document.querySelector('.submit-button-more').click()`.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly that you need to select an element using its name then 
using this way you can select with name

```
$('input[value="View more"]').click()
```

But i would suggest to always select any element using its id or class