# Press Button. Type in input box. Press submit

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, console

Say I visit a website which has the following code:

```
<input type="text" name="enter">
<input type="submit" name="button">

<a id="confirm">Confirm</a>
```

I need a script which I can run in the Chrome console to press the `<a>` element then type the text 'hello' into the input field and then click submit. I need this process to repeat every minute.

I have tried using this code.. but it doesn't do anything.

```
window.setInterval(function() { 
   document.querySelector("#confirm").click();     
   document.querySelector(".enter").value = "Hello";     
   document.querySelector(".button").click(); 
}, 1000);
```

Comment: This may be of help.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17300364/programmatically-clicking-all-buttons-on-a-page-in-chromes-console

Comment: @user685633 Thanks, but the problem is there's loads of buttons on the page! I just narrowed it down to the ones I need to click.. Also, I need to type into an input box.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a work request.

Comment: @SomeKittens I updated my post with what I tried

Comment: You're using query selector wrong. `.whatever` is for `class="whatever"`. `[name="whatever"]` is for `name="whatever"`/

Answer (score 1):

I think this might work

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('#confirm').trigger('click');
    $('input[name=enter]').setAttribute('value', 'Hello');
    $('input[name=button]').submit();
}, 1000);
```

without jquery

```
setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById('confirm').click();
    document.querySelector('input[name=enter]').setAttribute('value', 'Hello');
    document.querySelector('input[name=button]').submit();
}, 1000);
```

im not 100% sure wheither its [name='enter'] or [name=enter]

PS : selecting elements with a dot before means you're looking for the class name, not the element name.

Comment: The OP didn't mention that they're using JQUERY.

Comment: I added a non-jquery version ^^