# Combine multiple pages to print after clicking multiple buttons but only with Chrome Console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, printing, console, google-chrome-devtools

I know the title is a bit confusing but I'll try to explain what I'm trying to do. :)

Based on this question: [Programmatically clicking all buttons on a page in Chrome's console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17300364/programmatically-clicking-all-buttons-on-a-page-in-chromes-console)

I want to press all the buttons to pick items and print invoices in an e-commerce marketplace backend that I can only manipulate via the Chrome Console and then, logically, print all the invoices.

Pressing all the "pick" buttons works great but when I do the same for the "print" buttons, the browser only opens the print preview of the first button[0] once and all the others are ignored.

Is it somehow possible to print all documents or to collect them in a kind of array and then print them? Or is it possible to tell the browser not to show a print preview and print directly?

Comment: Sure, you can trigger a click on any button you want, but you have limited (no) control over that print functionality, as far as I know... That said, this question is a bit too broad.

Comment: You probably can yes, but how to do that depends on the website. Maybe you need to click 1 button, save the displayed content, then close the preview, and only then click on the next button. You can do a lot programmatically, but that depends on the website

Comment: @Ben
It's not the big problem to add a little delay between the clicks, the bigger problem is that as soon as the print preview opens I can't press any button in this new dialog using the usual methods via javascript.

Maybe you can suppress this print preview somehow and instead cache this document to be printed and then print the collected at once.